# Find radius and interval of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{5^n}{n+2^n}x^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Find radius and interval of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{5^n}{n+2^n}x^n$

So if i apply ratio test, I get $\lim_{x\to \infty} 5|x||\frac{n+2^n}{n+1+2^{n+1}}| $

Now need help to to check endpoints x= 2/5 and -2/5

If i put in x= 2/5 i get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{2^n}{n+2^n}$ How do i check if this converges or not? Same with x = -2/5 $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{(-2)^n}{n+2^n}$

Comment: Hint: Consider instead $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{2^n}+1}{\frac{n+1}{2^n}+2}$$ for the rightmost term.

Comment: limit is 1/2 thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By ratio test
$$ 5|x||\frac{n+2^n}{n+1+2^{n+1}}|\sim_\infty 5|x||\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}|=\frac{5}{2}|x|<1\iff|x|<\frac{2}{5}$$
hence the radius is $\frac{2}{5}$.

**Added**

-For $x=\frac{2}{5}$, $$\frac{5^n}{n+2^n}x^n=\frac{2^n}{n+2^n}\to1\neq0$$
so the series is divergent.

-For $x=-\frac{2}{5}$,
$$\frac{5^n}{n+2^n}x^n=\frac{(-1)^n2^n}{n+2^n}$$
has not a limit so the series is also divergent.

Comment: which series tests did you use? alternating series test for x= -2/5?

Comment: @josh No, I used the fact: if $u_n\not \to0$ then the series $\sum_n u_n$ is divergent.